# Create DSL Package in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dsl

I have a DSL project for VS2005(Active Writer Customized) .I want to make it compatible with VS2010.So

I migrated the project with DslProjectsMigrationTool.exe which comes with vs2010 SDK.

Created new dsl project in vs2010 and moved my migrated codes to the new project.

Here my Dsl project is building fine.But DslPackage project is showing the following build error.

**Error 48 : No Visual Studio registration attribute found in this assembly.**

But some blogs relates this error to RegPkg.And i don't have any idea about RegPkg.

Any solutions to resolve build error?

Comment: Did you try opening the old solution file using VS2010? It should prompt saying it will create a compatible version of it ...Generally VS08 projects can be converted to VS2010 but not sure about VS05

Comment: @dave- Thanks for reply..I migrated my vs2005 project with DslProjectsMigrationTool.exe and created a new dsl project in vs2010 and moved my migrated code to vs2010 project.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it could be to do with the RegPkg version. Perhaps try the solution discussed [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/85743471-3ebd-450e-bf8f-eed838961c67), which effectively uses Reflector to check which version of RegPkg is expected.